# Can't swiping between fragments in viewpager with buttons

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I would change fragment in the viewpager using a button in every fragment. So in the fragment in position 0 i have a button and onClick i'll change in second fragment (position 1) and so on. Actually i'm using this code in the fragment at position 0:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.open_welcome_fragment_layout, container,
                             false);
            final WelcomeViewPager pagerV = new WelcomeViewPager();
            Button nextBtnOpen = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_next_open);

            nextBtnOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((WelcomeViewPager)getActivity()).setCurrentItem(1, true);
                    }
                });
            return view;    
    }
```

position 1:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstwelcomefrg, container, false);
            final WelcomeViewPager pagerV = new WelcomeViewPager();
            Button nextBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_next_one);

             nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((WelcomeViewPager)getActivity()).setCurrentItem(2, true);
                    }
                });
            return view;
    }
```

position 2:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondwelcomefrg, container,
                             false);
            final WelcomeViewPager pagerV = new WelcomeViewPager();
            Button nextBtnTwo = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_next_two);

            nextBtnTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((WelcomeViewPager)getActivity()).setCurrentItem(3, true);
                    }
                });
            return view;    
    }
```

and in my ViewPager Activity i created this method:

```
public void setCurrentItem (int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
    }
```

unfortunatelly not works. I can change from first to second fragment but every fragment returns to second.. Seems that the only one position accepted is the first one. In this case:

```
((WelcomeViewPager)getActivity()).setCurrentItem(1, true);
```

why this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is to have tabs and each tab to help switch between views. You should use actionBar tabs for this, not buttons.

[This should help](http://semycolon.blogspot.in/2014/11/first-android-app-step-5-homescreen.html). It is a pretty detailed tutorial.

Comment: nope. i don't want the tabs.. My ViewPager is without them. It's 4 fragments in a viewpager without tabs.. Like the new gmail and google apps

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand...do you mean Gmail app or Gmail on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want Button ? I use for similary problem solving with  listener. Example of code below. Maybe help.

PagerActivity.java

```
import com.example.zzztest2.MyPagerAdapter.OnPagerItemSelected;

public class PagerActivity extends Activity implements OnPagerItemSelected  {

ViewPager viewPager;
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray=null;
ArrayList<String> textArray=null;
ArrayList<String> urlArray=null;  
int pagexi;   

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reklamapager);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

         //setting adapter
         new readAsync().execute();

  }//end oncreate

  //switch page
  public void pagerItemSelected(int newposition) {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(newposition);
  }
```

Setting my adapter in onpostexecute Async

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(PagerActivity.this, textArray, urlArray, bitmapArray, PagerActivity.this );
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            //start position
            int pagexi = 2;
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(pagexi);

        }
```

MyPagerAdapte.java

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


    Context context;
    OnPagerItemSelected mListener;
    ArrayList<String> textArray;
    ArrayList<String> urlArray;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textreklama1;
    Button btnSwitchPage;
    public Activity activity;
    String firmax;
    String adresarx;


    MyPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> textArray, ArrayList<String> urlArray, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray, OnPagerItemSelected listener){
        this.context=context;
        this.textArray=textArray;
        this.urlArray=urlArray;
        this.bitmapArray=bitmapArray;

        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return textArray.size();
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reklamator_new, null);


            String indexx = textArray.get(position).toString();
            String delims2 = "[;]+";
            String[] riadokxxx = indexx.split(delims2);
            String ucex =  riadokxxx[0].trim();
            String dokx =  riadokxxx[1].trim();



            EditText inputUce = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputUce);
            inputUce.setText(ucex);                 
            EditText inputDok = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputDok);
            inputDok.setText(dokx);                 

            btnSwitchPage = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSwitchPage);
            btnSwitchPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //here set new position
                    int xxx=1;
                    mListener.pagerItemSelected(xxx);

                }


            });


         ((ViewGroup) collection).addView(view, 0);
         return view;
         }

         @Override
         public void destroyItem(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
         ((ViewGroup) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
         }

         @Override
         public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
         return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
         }

         //new position
         public interface OnPagerItemSelected {
             void pagerItemSelected(int xxx);
         }


}
```

Comment: but..mmh...in the fragments?